# Sun's Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 on 64 bit Windows

Tags: java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I am having a 64 bit JDK installed on my laptop and to develop J2ME app, I recently installed Sun's WTK 2.5.2. When I m trying to run the project using this wtk, I m getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
```

Though my machine had an Intel core i3 processor(64 bits) the error says:

```
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit processor
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Is there anything else I can do to make J2ME App on my laptop?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.

Solved it by installing a 32 bit java, then re-installing the WTK, During installation it asks you witch JDK to use, then just point to the 32 bit java.

Answer (score 1):

Just install 32-bit JDK and everything will work. General rule is simple: 32 bit applications will use 32 bit JDK, 64-bit will use 64 bit JDK. Since WTK is 32 bit application - it would need 32 bit JDK

Answer (score 1):

Just edit to

```
C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre6\bin\java
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change to jdk of 32 bits, then you have to edit the file: "$WTK_HOME\bin\emulator.vm" and change the jdk in the first line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22\bin\java
```